# Why can't I install Sass on Mac OS?

Tags: ruby, sass

I have good output with `ruby -v` and I have good output with `gem -v`,
but when I use `sudo gem install sass`  it returns:

```
While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/sass
```

Why?